# Find longest interval between overlapping intervals in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, intervals, overlap

I have a list of intervals in the form of tuples such as this:

```py
data = [(5,10), (3,10), (13,15), (12,18), (20,29), (25,30)]
```

Each item in the tuple has 2 values (i.e., start, end) and there may or may not be overlaps between different intervals.   If there are overlapping intervals, I want to only take the longest ones.   The output in this test would be the following:

```
output = [(3,10), (12,18), (20,29)]
```

**How can I do this in Python using either the standard library, `numpy`,  or `pandas`?**

I started doing something naive like this but I don't think this will scale well...I also would rather not use `NetworkX`

```py
import networkx as nx
data = [(5,10), (3,10), (13,15), (12,18), (20,29), (25,30)]

graph = nx.Graph()

n = len(data)
for i, a in enumerate(data):
    a_seq = set(range(a[0], a[1] + 1))
   
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        b = data[j]
        b_seq = set(range(b[0], b[1] + 1))

        n_overlap = len(a_seq & b_seq)
        if n_overlap:
            graph.add_edge(a, b, weight=n_overlap)

output = list()
for nodes in nx.connected_components(graph):
    lengths = dict()
    for node in nodes:
        start, end = node
        lengths[node] = end - start
    longest_interval, length_of_interval = sorted(lengths.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[0]
    output.append(longest_interval)
```

I'm assuming there is a better approach but right now it's escaping me.

Edit: There might be some confusion in the task but I can't mix and match intervals (e.g., (20,30) is invalid because it's not one of the starting intervals).

Comment: The Problem is not welldefined: What should happen if you have 3 intervals, namely (1,5),(4,7) and (6,8)?  The longest one is (1,5) but that doesnt include (6,8). (4,7) Is longer than (6,8) though and overlaps. So is the solution [(1,5),(6,8)] or [(4,7)]?

Comment: In your example, why is 30 not covered in the output?

Comment: @Schorsch
In that case, I would say (1,5) would be the solution.  Thanks for bringing up more tricky cases.  The implementation I put above should handle that but I feel like it's kind of naive...

Comment: @Reinderien Because (20,29) interval is longer than the (25,30) overlapping interval.  I'll make a note that I can't mix and match intervals.

Comment: The edgecases is the interesting part with this :) So (1,5) is the solution and (6,8) is disregarded completely in that case?

Comment: Yup! Disregarded completely.  Take a look at the NetworkX implementation I made which is not optimized by any means. There's gotta be another way to think about this instead of graphs lol.

Comment: So are you looking for pair wise reduction, where (1,5), (4,7), (6,8) replaces the first two with (1,5) because that's the longest, leaving _both_ (1,5) and the now-not-overlapping (6,8)? Because why would (6,8) be removed? it does not overlap (1,5) at all.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans nope I would drop (6,8) in this case because it had overlaps with some of the others that were longer.

Comment: No, it didn't. It only overlapped (4,7) and we threw that away, so there is no overlap with any other interval.

Comment: (1,5) overlaps with (4,7) which overlaps with (6,8) so those are all one group. In that case, we take (1,5) because it's the longest of the group.

Comment: In your current implementation, intervals that do not overlap at all will be dropped. Also, intervals where the start point of one interval has the same value as the end point of another, i.e., adjacent intervals, are considered to overlap. Is this the expected behavior? Or are these just bugs?

Comment: @ken That's a great point!  Ok yes, solo intervals that have no overlap should still be included.  There shouldn't be any duplicate intervals in the input.

Comment: What about adjacent? For example, `[(1, 3), (3, 10)]`. Your code thinks they are overlapping and will only output `(3, 10)` as the longer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post mentioned not using any libraries so that's what I did. Also, you mentioned many clarifications in the comments so this code handles all the edge cases.

```python
def find_max_length_in_overlap_groups(intervals):
    #get sorted list of intervals by starting point
    aux = sorted(intervals, key=lambda x: x[0])
    new_group = [aux[0]]
    output = []
    for interval in aux[1:]:
        if interval[0] > new_group[-1][-1]:
        #if the interval does not overlap with the last interval we start a new group
            output.append(
                #find interval of maximum length
                max(new_group, key=lambda interval: interval[1] - interval[0])
            )
            #start new group
            new_group = [interval]
        else:
            #otherwise just append it onto the same group if it overlaps
            new_group.append(interval)
    #take care of the last group, doing the same as above
    output.append(max(new_group, key=lambda interval: interval[1] - interval[0]))
    return output
```

This approach is based on a solution for a similar problem found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/), with a more complete explanantion. This approach doesn't preserve the original ordering of the output. If you want that you have to modify the function slightly, by storing the original indices and then sorting by them:

```python
def find_max_length_in_overlap_groups(intervals):
    #store the indices
    indices={val:ind for ind, val in enumerate(intervals)}
    aux = sorted(intervals, key=lambda x: x[0])
    new_group = [aux[0]]
    output = []
    for interval in aux[1:]:
        if interval[0] > new_group[-1][-1]:
            output.append(
                max(new_group, key=lambda interval: interval[1] - interval[0])
            )
            new_group = [interval]
        else:
            new_group.append(interval)
    output.append(max(new_group, key=lambda interval: interval[1] - interval[0]))
    #sort the output according to indices in input to preserve order
    return sorted(output, key = lambda x: indices[x])
```

Both algorithms have the same time complexity: `O(n log n)` due to the sorting

Answer (score 1):

That is infact a good example of graph theory however it should be possible using only numpy by starting with the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

The adjacency matrix basically assigns a `1` to every two list element indices that are connected a `0` to all others thereby defining your undirected graph in a 2 dimensional array.

The classic approach would be to then implement depth first search or something in that manner however [this answer on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3726603/407457) has a pretty nice approach using the Laplacian Matrix and finding Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors. ([Both are implemented in numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html))

```py
from itertools import groupby

import numpy as np

data = [(5, 10), (3, 10), (13, 15), (12, 18), (20, 29), (25, 30)]


def overlap(a, b):
    return int((a[0] <= b[1]) and (b[0] <= a[1]))


l = len(data)

# Create Adjecency Matrix
A = np.array([[(overlap(data[i], data[j])) for i in range(l)] for j in range(l)])

# Create Laplacian
L = np.eye(l) - A

# Get Eigenvectors
_, eig_vect = np.linalg.eig(L)

# get inidces of non-zero entries
r, c = np.nonzero(eig_vect.transpose())

# group non-zero entries and remove duplicate groups
group_ix = {
    tuple(val[1] for val in group)
    for _, group in groupby(list(enumerate(c)), key=lambda x: r[x[0]])
}

# find largest interval in data for every group
largest_obj = [
    data[group[np.argmax([data[i][1] - data[i][0] for i in group])]]
    for group in group_ix
]
```

This gives the desired answer for your provided data. To fine-tune what you see as "belongs to one group" you can tweak the `overlap` function accordingly.

Comment: Doing some test.  It looks like this one fails on: `data = [(1086, 1211), (1860, 2581), (2686, 2886), (2925, 3187), (3194, 3319), (3607, 3726), (3748, 3900), (3973, 6159), (4189, 6159), (6163, 6255), (6600, 6707)]` where it includes both `(3973, 6159), (4189, 6159)`

Comment: @O.rka you're right, I did not transpose the eigen_vector in `r, c = np.nonzero(eig_vect.transpose())` I edited my answer. It worked with your first example beacuse every two neighbouring elements belonged to one group (so acidentally works for transposed and non-transposed eigenvectors)

Answer (score 1):

If performance doesn't matter much, you could have easily implemented this by using [intervaltree](https://github.com/chaimleib/intervaltree).

```py
from typing import Iterable, List, Tuple
from intervaltree import IntervalTree


def merge_overlaps_by_intervaltree(intervals: Iterable[Tuple[int, int]]) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
    tree = IntervalTree()
    for interval in intervals:
        tree.addi(begin=interval[0], end=interval[1], data=interval)
    tree.merge_overlaps(data_reducer=lambda x, y: x if x[1] - x[0] >= y[1] - y[0] else y)
    return [interval.data for interval in sorted(tree)]
```

However, this library does a bit of unnecessary work for your objective, so I implemented a faster one.

```py
from typing import Iterable, List, Tuple
import operator


def merge_overlaps(intervals: List[Tuple[int, int]], merge_adjacent: bool = False) -> Iterable[Tuple[int, int]]:
    # You can delete this line if intervals are guaranteed to be sorted.
    intervals = sorted(intervals)

    # The start/stop of the group of overlapping intervals currently being updated.
    group_start, group_stop = intervals[0]

    # The longest interval currently found in the current group.
    longest_interval = (group_start, group_stop)
    longest_length = group_stop - group_start

    # Whether adjacent (e.g. [(1,3),(3,10)]) are considered overlapping or not.
    is_overlapped = operator.le if merge_adjacent else operator.lt

    for interval_start, interval_stop in intervals[1:]:
        interval_length = interval_stop - interval_start
        if is_overlapped(interval_start, group_stop):  # This interval can be merged into the group.
            if interval_length > longest_length:  # Update the longest interval.
                longest_interval = (interval_start, interval_stop)
                longest_length = interval_length
            if interval_stop > group_stop:  # Update the group range.
                group_stop = interval_stop
        else:  # This interval cannot be merged into the group. A new group must be created.
            yield longest_interval  # Before creating a new group, output the previous group.
            group_start, group_stop = interval_start, interval_stop
            longest_interval = (interval_start, interval_stop)
            longest_length = interval_length

    yield longest_interval
```

This should work fast even with large input because it does not create intermediate objects that grow proportional to the amount of input or overlap (except for the sorted intervals).

Note that regarding the adjacent intervals that I asked about in the comment, you can change the behavior with the `merge_adjacent` argument.

Example:

```py
data = [(5, 10), (3, 10), (13, 15), (12, 18), (20, 29), (25, 30)]
print(list(merge_overlaps(data)))
# [(3, 10), (12, 18), (20, 29)]

data = [(1, 5), (4, 7), (6, 8)]
print(list(merge_overlaps(data)))
# [(1, 5)]

data = [(1, 3), (3, 10)]
print(list(merge_overlaps(data)))
# [(1, 3), (3, 10)]

data = [(1, 3), (3, 10)]
print(list(merge_overlaps(data, merge_adjacent=True)))
# [(3, 10)]
```

Comment: The question asked for a solution not using the any libraries including the standard library. Though your solution can be easily re-written to match this requirement by using ```lambda```s instead of ```operator```, and ```typing``` is completely optional but good practice.

Comment: @YEpd: The OP states "using either the standard library, ..." so I thought we were allowed to use these, but was there such a requirement?

Comment: Apologies, I misread the OPs question, great solution utilising generators.